# Axios request in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a post request from a register form to a fake api made with json server but I keep getting the error 400 Bad Request.

```
const managerRegister = () => {

    const [manager, setManager] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    accessLevel: 2,
    company: "",
  })
  
  console.log(manager)

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
      axios.post(`https://reembolsa-ai-api.herokuapp.com/register`, manager)
      .then(res => setManager(res))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
    
I'm using an ant-design form so it already comes with a function onFinish that handles the actions to be taken when the form is submitted 

const onFinish = (values) => {
    handleSubmit(values)
  };
```

I tried to use the axios request in useEffect but it does not work neither.

})

and I need to pass those information to the api. I tried

Comment: status 400 means you're sending something that is not right to the server. Kindly check your network tab for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This code working fine for me. I think you should fill the params like this.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
export default function ManagerRegister() {
  const [manager, setManager] = useState({
    email: "tester1@gmail.com",
    password: "tester",
    confirmPassword: "tester",
    accessLevel: 2,
    company: "Test",
  }) 
  
  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    axios.post(`https://reembolsa-ai-api.herokuapp.com/register`, manager)
    .then(res => setManager(res))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
 }
}
```

Comment: Because your api require email atrribute is present and unique. If you want to get success response you should change the email value